# Understanding PHP caching - what happens to JavaScript? - using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to understand PHP caching. I'm using Symfony 2 and trying to get something together.

Image a gateway cache or reverse proxy cache that caches the full page. How does JavaScript get affected by this?

So imagine you had a page that rarely changed (maybe once a week) - you could probably cache it for a week. But imagine you had a JavaScript function that did something on that page, say a collapsible script. Imagine by default the HTML shows all panels open, and the JS remembers a value in local storage and after page load it closes the panels that need to (remembering the state). How would this affect caching?

So for me the best way would be that only the HTML is cached and then the JS gets executed afterward anyway (and no doubt the JS files are already cached). Or does it sort of take a screenshot and if the page is cached with half the collapsible panels open and half closed then they will always look like that (until the cache is cleared).

I'm trying to work out if ESI is better, or how I should create something so as to be able to utilise caching but still keep certain dynamic features. The best way would be to cache all HTML and allow the JS, CSS and everything else to run again from the cached JS/CSS file, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any caching is to do with how data gets from the server to the client (e.g. a web browser); it has nothing to do with how that data is interpreted by the client. (Think of a really slow PHP script which outputs a text file; what the text file is used for is irrelevant, it is the slow PHP you are avoiding with the cache.)

You cannot cache the on-screen rendering of an HTML page, because that rendering is entirely the browser's job (hence why different browsers may render things differently). Execution of JS is just like rendering the HTML - part of the browser's interpretation of the content.

So the answer to your question is that caching will make no difference to your JS whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The cache only saves the HTML as it is delivered by the server.  If javascript modifies the DOM, the DOM that is cached is unaffected by the javascript.  The javascript will run everytime, regardless of whether the HTML is served "fresh" or from the cache.  Pretty much the only issue you have to worry about with caching is making sure the cache gets updated when it should, so you aren't serving a "stale" cache.